# React, Agregar objeto a state lista de objetos

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usestate

estoy intentando agregar un objeto a un state array. Deberia funcionar como un push, que no sobrescriba, sino que agregue. Este seria el codigo. La funcion recibe bien el producto, pero no me guarda el objeto producto en la lista listOfProducts. Esa seria la duida

```
const [listOfProducts, setListOfProducts] = useState([]);

  const addProductToList = (product) => {
    console.log('product band', product);
    setListOfProducts((listOfProducts) => [...listOfProducts, product]); //esto no me anda

    console.log('product added', listOfProducts);
  };
```

Comment: Prueba con esto `setListOfProducts([...listOfProducts, product])`

Comment: me pasa lo mismo, es raro. En el primer console.log que muestra el objeto recibido, me muestra todo ok. ahora a la primera vez q ejecuta la funcion no me agrega el objeto a la lista, solo un parametro del objeto, el id. Luego, si ejecuto de nuevo la funcion me empieza a agregar el objeto ok. es como q la primera vez no agrega nada y luego agrega el objeto atrasado q no agrego antes....debo tener algo mal en otro lado del codigo

Comment: Lo que buscas es poder ver `listOfProducts` actualizado en el segundo `console.log`, es decir aquí : `console.log('product added', listOfProducts);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [listOfProducts, setListOfProducts] = useState([]);

 const addProductToList = (product) => {
    setListOfProducts([...listOfProducts, product]); //esto debería de funcionar
    console.log('product added', listOfProducts);
 };
```

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles a tu respuesta: si bien puede ser útil al OP, necesitas detallar tu respuesta para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer].

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la retroalimentación, saludos corregiré eso :)

Answer (score 0):

hola el error es que no estas agregando al estado anterior, al usar hooks tienes que usar una variable que represente al valor anterior

setListOfProducts((estadoprevio) => [...estadoprevio, product]);
y eso deberia actualizarte el estado de ListOfProducts